# How to write two concurrent async parallel function and execute one with another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

How to have two concurrent process pool, to speed up the function,

I am trying to parallel executing `test` function from inside `func` function,

Is there any better way I can run one parallel concurrent async function within another?

NOTE: this is a basic example of my original func, I am looking way to parallelize a another parallel function.

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import multiprocessing as mp
import asyncio


def arg(x):
    print("Hello", x)


async def test(x):
    print(x)
    asyncio_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(6) as pool:
        results = [asyncio_loop.run_in_executor(pool, arg, x) for x in range(10)]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*results)
        return results


async def func():
    asyncio_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(6) as loop:
        results = [asyncio_loop.run_in_executor(loop, test, x) for x in range(10)]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*results)
        return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(func())
    loop.close()
```

Here's the error,

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 29, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(func())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "testing.py", line 23, in func
    results = await asyncio.gather(*results)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'coroutine' object
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go through additional steps to parallelize a function that is *already async*. Since `test` is async, the correct way to write `func` would be:

```
async def func():
    return await asyncio.gather(*[test(x) for x in range(10)])
```

Also, note that creating a process pool each time a function is invoked means that the processes will be freshly started. It's a better idea to make the pool global and just reuse it (without the `with` statement) every time you need it. That way the already-started processes will be reused, and form the "pool" the class name refers to.